# Two nodes subscribed to each other that should count do not start unless I force a publisher

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the code for the first node called /first which is subscribed to /second_channel and publishes to /first_channel

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
rospy.init_node('second')
bar = rospy.Publisher('first_channel', Int32, queue_size=10)
count = 0
def callback(msg):
     count = msg.data
     print count

bar.publish(count+1)

sub = rospy.Subscriber('second_channel', Int32, callback)
bar.publish(count)
rospy.spin()
```

Here is the code for the second node called /second which is subscribed to /first_channel and publishes to /second_channel

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
rospy.init_node('first')
foo = rospy.Publisher('second_channel', Int32, queue_size=10)
count = 0
def callback(msg):
    count = msg.data
    print count
    foo.publish(count+1)

sub = rospy.Subscriber('first_channel', Int32, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

When I start both of these in terminal, they are running without anything published and the rqt_graph command shows that they are subscribed to each other. But when I run: 'rostopic pub -1 /first_channel std_msgs/Int32 2' both nodes start passing the counter back and forth correctly. How can I make the passing back and forth start?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280455/two-nodes-subscribed-to-each-other-that-should-count-do-not-start-unless-i-force-a-publisher/) by [hstusnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/33381/hstusnick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting up subscriptions takes time.

Make both of them wait until there is at least one subscriber to their topic.

Use [Publisher::getNumSubscribers()](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html#ad56c8e954020290dcb87cd6bbd330a2b) for that.

Some related questions:

- #q11167: *How do I publish exactly one message?*
- #q32952: *With rospy, messages don't seem to be recieved if published soon after creating the publisher*
- #q82536: *ROS misses some messages*

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
Note also that there is no guarantee of delivery anywhere in ROS 1 pub-sub. So if you have data that absolutely *must* get to 'the other side', pub-sub is perhaps not what you should use.